# What's wrong with this SQL INSERT prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, prepared-statement

I'm creating a user registration system for my website. I had this working code:

```
$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO GH_users (firstname, surname, email, accountConfirmed, username, passwordHash)
        VALUES ('$firstname', '$surname', '$email', 0, '$usernameSignup', '$passwordHash')";
$execute = $dbConn->exec($sqlQuery);
```

However, I found out that this invites the risk of SQL injection. Therefore, I have tried to use a prepared statement to prevent this but I am unable to get it to work. Codes that I've tried:

```
$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO GH_users (firstname, surname, email, accountConfirmed, username, passwordHash)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $dbConn->prepare($sqlQuery);
        $stmt->bindParam($firstname, $surname, $email, 0, $usernameSignup, $passwordHash);
        $stmt->execute();

$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO GH_users (firstname, surname, email, accountConfirmed, username, passwordHash)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, 0, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $dbConn->prepare($sqlQuery);
        $stmt->bindParam("sssss", $firstname, $surname, $email, $usernameSignup, $passwordHash);
        $stmt->execute();
// These give the following error: PDOStatement::bindParam() expects at most 5 parameters, 6 given

// So I tried this:
$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO GH_users (firstname, surname, email, accountConfirmed, username, passwordHash)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, 0, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $dbConn->prepare($sqlQuery);
        $stmt->bindParam($firstname, $surname, $email, $usernameSignup, $passwordHash);
        $stmt->execute();
// But this throws: PDOStatement::bindParam() expects parameter 3 to be long, string given
```

I'm not sure why these are throwing the errors given, especially the "expects parameter 3 to be long" as the email field is a string (varchar) data type. Can anyone help with this and explain what is wrong(accountConfirmed is a bit if it helps)?

**UPDATE**

I realised that I was receiving these errors because I was not using prepared statements and bound parameters in PDO. Thanks to @tadman and @user3783243 in the comment section, I was able to shorten my code by adding my parameters to `execute()` to do the binding instead of using `bindParam()` for each of the parameters.

**SOLUTION**

```
$sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO GH_users (firstname, surname, email, accountConfirmed, username, passwordHash)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, 0, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $dbConn->prepare($sqlQuery);
        $stmt->execute(array($firstname, $surname, $email, $usernameSignup, $passwordHash));
```

Comment: Are you connecting using `PDO` or `MYSQLI_` or `MYSQL_`

Comment: I am connecting with PDO

Comment: According to [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php) it looks like you need to bind them one at a time.

Comment: Thanks for your question @RiggsFolly. From that, I realised that I was using the mySQL prepared statement way to bind my parameters.

Comment: @Uueerdo: Thanks for the link!

Comment: As a reminder, PDO can take arguments to `execute()` to do the binding then. Way more convenient.

Comment: Yes, see tadman comment. Huge benefit of PDO. You must have been using `mysqli` manual. Basically `$stmt->execute(array($firstname, $surname, $email, $usernameSignup, $passwordHash))` should do it. Don't need `bindparam`.